# DCC GARCH in Stata

Tags: stata, garch

I want to estimate the dynamic conditional correlation GARCH in stata 12. I just ran the following line:

```
mgarch dcc (x y =, noconstant) , arch(1) garch(1)
```

The x and the y variables are log first differences from two price series.

My questions are as follows:

1. Does anybody know how I obtain the parameter estimates for the elements of Ht?
2. Is it correct that I directly put the log first differences in this model or should I first obtain the residuals from a AR model?

Comment: Actually you need to prewhiten the series before running the model. Usually this is done by fitting a VAR model and applying the DCC GARCH model to the residuals of the VAR, or estimating both models in one-step. I'm not sure how to do it in stata, but you can do this one-step estimation with the [rmgarch](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/rmgarch.pdf) package in R.

Answer (score 1):

1. Type predict H*,variance
2. I think log first differences or other types depends on your purpose of setting model, not relevant with Dcc model.